# R predict on new data with less levels of categorical variable than in training data

Tags: r, classification, predict, one-hot-encoding

I need to do a classification (R xgboost or catboost etc) on some data, which has together about 30 input variables. One of the dataset variables is a factor variable, with 100 possible levels ("n01", "n02", ..., "n100") in the training and test sets. So when I use one hot encoding on existing data (with R sparse.model.matrix) I get 100 new columns, one column for each level of the factor.

So I make a model (train, test etc) with  the dataset, including these 100 levels of factor variable. But when I need to predict (use the model) on new data, there are only a few new data samples and then I get less levels of this factor variable.
Both xgboost and catboost give an error, that feature names are different.

Idea to include data for prediction into data for model creation is not acceptable, because I need to make a model once, and then use it for prediction on new data each time.

What are the possible ways to solve this problem?

Comment: You should have a record of all the column names in your training data, and add any missing columns to your prediction data with `0` values.

Comment: You can also have a `factor` with levels without observations, e.g, `x = factor(c("a", "b"), levels = letters)`. Some methods for one-hot-encoding are smart enough to add columns for the unobserved levels. This is probably the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this shows you the way.  You can encode your categorical variables as `factor` with the full set of levels and then use `model.matrix` to expand these into dummies.

Note how in my example, the `colnames(x_test)` command shows the full set of dummies despite only two levels of `z` being present in the test data.

Take care that the factor variables in your test data have the same levels as those in the train data.  If the train and test data both originated from the same data frame, this should require no extra care.  If the train and test data are originating from different sources, you need to set the levels of the factors in the test data to be the same as the test.  I show this in this answer using `|> factor(levels(train_data$z))`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(xgboost)

# simulated data ----
  
train_data <- expand_grid(
  z = as.factor(letters[1:10]),
  id = 1:10
) |> 
  mutate(
    x1 = runif(100), x2 = runif(100), x3 = runif(100),
    y = x1 + x2 + 0.1*x3 + rnorm(100)
  )

test_data <- expand_grid(
  z = letters[4:5] |> factor(levels(train_data$z)),
) |> 
  mutate(
    x1 = runif(2), x2 = runif(2), x3 = runif(2),
    y = x1 + x2 + 0.1*x3 + rnorm(2)
  )

print(train_data)
#> # A tibble: 100 × 6
#>    z        id      x1    x2      x3      y
#>    <fct> <int>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 a         1 0.885   0.586 0.437    0.195
#>  2 a         2 0.776   0.981 0.758    1.08 
#>  3 a         3 0.578   0.835 0.419    1.15 
#>  4 a         4 0.00173 0.619 0.864    1.97 
#>  5 a         5 0.317   0.234 0.620    1.26 
#>  6 a         6 0.100   0.556 0.651    1.92 
#>  7 a         7 0.388   0.202 0.198    0.138
#>  8 a         8 0.374   0.972 0.0275   2.74 
#>  9 a         9 0.944   0.776 0.140    0.911
#> 10 a        10 0.200   0.488 0.00789 -0.647
#> # ℹ 90 more rows
print(test_data)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   z         x1    x2    x3     y
#>   <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 d     0.758  0.986 0.785  1.63
#> 2 e     0.0283 0.270 0.235 -1.59

# model ----

form <- y ~ z + x1 + x2 + x3

x <- model.matrix(form, train_data)[, -1]
y <- train_data$y

model <- xgboost(x, y, nrounds = 10)
#> [1]  train-rmse:0.910737 
#> [2]  train-rmse:0.761354 
#> [3]  train-rmse:0.658591 
#> [4]  train-rmse:0.567893 
#> [5]  train-rmse:0.516402 
#> [6]  train-rmse:0.476570 
#> [7]  train-rmse:0.430633 
#> [8]  train-rmse:0.390250 
#> [9]  train-rmse:0.355300 
#> [10] train-rmse:0.333189

# predict ----

x_test <- model.matrix(form, test_data)[, -1]
colnames(x_test)
#>  [1] "zb" "zc" "zd" "ze" "zf" "zg" "zh" "zi" "zj" "x1" "x2" "x3"
predict(model, x_test)
#> [1] 1.3814828 0.3808365
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>